# tsc - pretty format for light terminals

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, tsc

I often use light-colored terminals, I see this:

[image]

**It's hard to read the cyan and yellow.**... Is there a setting I can use in tsconfig.json that can tell `tsc` to output colors that are easier to see in a light colored terminal?

Right now I am using `"pretty":true` but maybe there is another setting?